# Misuse of past perfect or just ignore it?

Tags: grammaticality

Why do I hear many Americans saying things like "I had ate all I could" or "I had went to the school earlier?" Anyone else notice this or am I being overly strict?

Comment: This is a non-standard dialect.  Why are you asking?

Comment: Yes misuse.  Yes ignore.

Comment: That's the way it works in their dialect of English. This is spoken, not written.